# Find an explicit example of a bounded sequence $e_n$ such that $e_n ≥ 0$ for all $n \in N$, and $((e_n)^n + 2^n)^\frac 1n$ does not converge

Tags: real-analysis

Find an explicit example of a bounded sequence $e_n$ such that $e_n ≥ 0$ for all $n \in N$, and $((e_n)^n + 2^n)^\frac 1n$ does not converge and prove it.

I'm having a really tough time finding an example sequence that is non-negative, bounded and then makes $((e_n)^n + 2^n)^\frac 1n$  not converge. I thought I would first try to find sequences that made $((e_n)^n + 2^n)^\frac 1n$ not converge, but I'm struggling to find examples even for that. I would appreciate any help with trying to find some examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Take $e_n=1$ for odd $n$ and $e_n=3$ for even $n$. Then $(e_{2n-1}^{2n-1}+2^{2n-1})^{1/{(2n-1)}} \to 2$ and  $(e_{2n}^{2n}+2^{2n})^{1/{(2n)}} \to 3$.

[Note: $0< a <b$ implies $ b\leq (a^{n}+b^{n})^{1/n}\leq (b^{n}+b^{n})^{1/n}= 2^{1/n}b$ (and $2^{1/n} \to 1$) so  $(a^{n}+b^{n})^{1/n} \to b$].

Comment: @DanSmith If $c_n$ is sequence such that the odd terms of the  sequence have a limit different from the even terms then the sequence itself does not converge.